# Make div appears if any of the checkbox is checked!

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on dynamic site where **multiple checkboxes** are there with **unique ID**,

What I want is new `<div>` to **appear if any of the checkbox is checked** & **disappears if all the checkboxes are unchecked**.

New to javascripts, need your help.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
 #appear_div {
     display: none;
 }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function doInputs(obj){
 var checkboxs = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked"); 
 var i =0, box;
 $('#appear_div').fadeOut('fast');
     while(box = checkboxs[i++]){
     if(!box.checked)continue;
     $('#appear_div').fadeIn('fast');
     break;
     }
 }
 </script>

 <form>
 <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="doInputs(this)">
 <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="doInputs(this)">
 <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="doInputs(this)">
 <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="doInputs(this)">
 <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="doInputs(this)">
 </form>
 <div id="appear_div">
 <input type="text">
 </div>
```

This worked for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

recommended to learn Jquery

http://jquery.org/

you can put an ascending id  like chekboxid1 , checkboxid2 ....

and check if all be checked :

```
$('[id^=checkboxid]').live('click', function(){
var total = {insert the sum of checkbox}
    if($("[id^=checkboxid]:checked").length == total){
    // do something
}
});
```

to know if all unchecked compare the length 0 , instead of total.

another link more detailed :

http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/8/14/jQuery--Accessing-Checked-Checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do something similar using jQuery.

First hide the area onload so the user cannot see it

```
 <style>
     #div2appear{
         display: none;
     }
 </style>
```

Then the form elements

```
 <form id="AllTheseFields">
   <input type="checkbox" name="c1" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="c1" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="c1" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="c1" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="c1" />
   <div id="div2appear">
     <input type="text" />
   </div>
 </form>
```

And the jQuery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#AllTheseFields>input[type=checkbox]').change(
       function(){
           if($('#AllTheseFields>input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')){
                  // if any of the checkboxes are checked then make the area visible
                  $('#div2appear').show(); 
           }else{
                  // only if all are unchecked will this fire and hide the area
                  $('#div2appear').hide();
           }
       }
    );
 </script>
```